# Solution for identify mobile devices by mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, mobile-application

I'm wondering it's possible to identify android device by web app running on mobile web browser? And this solution have to still working after change or upgrade web browser on this phone.

My second doubt is web app can working offline on phone showing PDF presentations saved in local storage (disk). When I have internet connection I can manually sync presentations (some are removed and some are downloaded).

If PWA app can work like I described above or in this case we need to use (hybrid) mobile app ?

Answer (score 2):

PWAs allow to cache assets and make them available to the users even when they are offline. There are some functionalities that only Native Apps have (eg. access to a device contacts), but they are very close under many other aspects.

I wrote an article about [Service Workers and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) where I explain how to cache static assets as well as HTTP GET calls. It is part of a series about PWAs, so you might find it useful to get more insights about this technology.

Have a look at the website [what web can do today](https://whatwebcando.today/) to have a list of WEB APIs currently available:

[image]

I do not know the detail of your requirements, but maybe you do not even need to implement an hybrid app and simply create a PWA.